# What was the Robot Defense Act going to do?

Tags: robopocalypse

In *Robopocalypse*, as Congresswoman Laura Perez learns about and encounters what appears to be malfunctioning robots, she prepares to introduce *The Robot Defense Act*.  Her daughter, Mathilda is attacked/approached by her Baby-Comes-Alive doll, which warns Mathilda that the Robot Defense Act won't protect them.

Everything I recall about the Robot Defense Act in the book was just stating that it would somehow help defend humans from the robots.

**What was being proposed by the Robot Defense Act?**

Comment: I couldn't find anything online, but I would guess that it's something like a requirement to dismantle all robots, or maybe a prohibition on the further construction of robots. If you're looking for something canon, I'm afraid this won't help.